# how to hosting JAVA PLAY framework on server

Tags: playframework, hosting

is there any link or video that I can watch to guide me in hosting play framework application? thanks.

I've tried but failed.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production

Comment: You can look or checkout my github repo and see the source files. I deployed the project on heroku. Its easy to setup an project on heroku.
https://github.com/aBuder/herokuPlay

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to get familiar with Play framework with their documentation.  There is also some suggestion I would like to share with you. For example: if you want to learn more about JPA, you should refer to the JPA related website. Play use Ebean as default implementation, you can find the website here: http://www.avaje.org/doc/ebean-userguide.pdf . Anyway, the docs in their website is the best lesson.